# Setting project indentation settings to tabs with CMake generated Xcode project

Tags: xcode, cmake

I have a project which configures builds using CMake. I'd like to make it so that when CMake generates an Xcode project, it sets Xcode to use tabs instead of spaces. Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks :)

Comment: Seems not implemented yet: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17042